# Set row height using excellibrary

Tags: c#, size, cell, excellibrary

I'm using excellibrary and I want to set a row's height or column's width. Sounds very simple, but I can't find a solution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are referring to [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)? I don't have it loaded up in front of me at the moment, but if memory serves, try:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet");

worksheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell("Cell 0,0");
worksheet.Cells[1, 0] = new Cell("Cell 1,0");

ushort currentHeight = worksheet.Cells.GetRowHeight(1); 
worksheet.Cells.GetRow(1).Height = (ushort)(currentHeight + 20);

workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
workbook.Save(filePath); // will need to set filepath
```

**Edit:** While in theory this is correct, I'm actually **not sure this property works** (after a quick test in Excel 2010 and Excel 2007).

If you follow the source code then apparently the [`Row`](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/ExcelLibrary/Office/Excel/SpreadSheet/Row.cs?r=40) class `Height` <strike>property</strike> public field does get written out by the [`WorksheetEncoder` line 55](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/ExcelLibrary/Office/Excel/BinaryFileFormat/Encode/WorkSheetEncoder.cs#55), and in turn through the [`ROW`](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/ExcelLibrary/Office/Excel/BinaryFileFormat/Records/ROW.cs) class [`Encode`](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/ExcelLibrary/Office/Excel/BinaryFileFormat/Records/ROW.cs#72) method into the `Stream` writing out the workbook, but if I then open in Excel, it doesn't work. (I don't have Excel versions before 2007 to test in).

Unfortunately there is no other property to use to set the row height. This is the one that gets used by the `BinaryWriter` to generate the workbook.

Also note, if you are targeting Excel 2010 you will need to pad out a chunk of cells in the above sample to make sure the final file is big enough for Excel 2010 to be happy. e.g.:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(); 
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet"); 

//  Excel 2010 hack - issue 102
for (int r = 0; r < 150; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
        worksheet.Cells[r, c] = new Cell(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, it doesn't work for me too. What workaround would you recommend? Maybe to set that without excellibrary and with some else library if possible?

Comment: I think if row height is important, you need to switch completely to another approach, such as Visual Studio [office solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620922.aspx).